# the algebraic closure of strict henselian DVR

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a strict henselian DVR, and $\hat A$ is completion of $A$,

is $K(A)^{alg} \longrightarrow  {K(\hat A)}^{alg}$ a isomorphism?

where $K(A)$ and  $K(\hat A)$ are quotient fields.

Answer (score 6):

No, since $K(\hat{A})$ is usually transcendental over $K(A)$.

Let $A$ be the strict henselization of $\mathbb Q[x]$ at $x=0$. Then $A$ is contained in $\mathbb Q(x)^{alg}$, thus $K(A)^{alg}=\mathbb Q(x)^{alg}$, a countable field. But $\hat{A}$ is $\mathbb Q^{alg}[[x]]$ and has a bijection to $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb Q^{alg}$ and so is uncountable, so $K(\hat{A})^{alg}$ is uncoutnable.

Comment: Do $K(A)$ and $K(\hat A)$ have isomorphic absolute Galois groups?

Comment: @zzy I think always yes. The main thing to check is that every algebraic extension of $K(\hat{A})$ is defined over $K(A)$. To do that, you want to check that if you perturb the coefficients of the defining equation slightly, you get the same Galois extension. This is some famous theorem.

Comment: Thank you, what you say looks like Krasner's lemma. Before I found something related in the tilting approach to the proof of Fontaine-Winterberger theorem while he didn't give a proof and I come across this problem while searching on mathoverflow.

Comment: @zzy You are right, I have never once in my life remembered the name "Krasner's lemma".